# Fundamental group of manifold and axiom of choice

Tags: algebraic-topology, set-theory, manifolds, axiom-of-choice, fundamental-groups

It is known that the fundamental group of a manifold must be countable.

As far as I am aware, a proof of this uses in an essential way the Axiom of Countable Choice.

I was wondering: is it consistent with ZF that there exists a manifold with uncountable fundamental group? I wasn't able to find any reference concerning this.

Edit: This result is found, for instance, as Theorem 7.21 in John Lee's book [Introduction to Topological Manifolds](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4419-7940-7).

Comment: I am not familiar with the theorem or the proof, so I can't quite help there. But if you can provide some references to why and where it is known, I'd be happy to try and take a look.

Comment: As long as manifolds are required to be separable and finite-dimensional, standard absoluteness arguments should imply that choice has no essential role here.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have added a reference. Essentially, you take a countable cover by coordinate balls and use them to choose a countable collection of loops which represent every homotopy class in the fundamental group.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I am not familiar with this kind of arguments, but can they be used to extract an explicit proof of this result that does not rely on choice? In the reference that I added, I don't see an immediate way to avoid this.

Comment: @J.C. Yes, but the explicit proof we're guaranteed to get goes through set theory so it may not feel very satisfying. That said, in most situations we can get a reasonably-natural choiceless proof by thinking about the particulars a bit more carefully.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: It seems very plausible to me that proving a smooth manifold is triangulable would use countable choice.  For instance, I don't see any obvious way to avoid countable choice in proving the existence of partitions of unity.

Comment: The basic difficulty seems to stem from the fact that the standard definition involves assuming just second countability, rather than some stronger countability condition.  For instance, if you assume not just second countability but that there exists a countable atlas, then things seem much easier to prove without choice.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, Evidently, not everybody participating in this discussion is aware of the fact that you provided an answer.  You may want to elaborate on what you mean by "absoluteness" and why it solves the problem.

Comment: @EricWofsey ZF proves second countable locally compact Hausdorff spaces (e.g. any reasonable manifold) are Polish, so manifolds can be coded by reals. Thus, all those properties of manifolds are provable in ZF by absoluteness.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental group of a second-countable manifold is countable, without any choice.

First, notice that we can find a countable base $B$ such that each basis element is a subset of a contractible set.  This implies that for any $U \in B$ and points $x, y \in U$, any two paths from $x$ to $y$ within $U$ are homotopic in the manifold.

By compactness of $[0,1]$, any loop contains a finite sequence of points $x_0, x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n = x_0$ such that the path from $x_{i-1}$ to $x_i$ lies entirely in some $U_i \in B$.  Since $B$ is a basis, we can also choose $x_i \in V_i \in B$ such that $V_i$ is contained in a connected component of $U_i \cap U_{i+1}$.

Thus for each loop, we have a (non-unique) description $U_1 \supset V_1 \subset U_2 \supset \cdots \subset U_n$.  Since $B$ is countable, there are only countably many such descriptions.  All that remains is to show that any two loops admitting the same description are homotopic.

Let $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ be two loops that admit the same description.  We have corresponding sequences of points $x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n$ and $x'_0, x'_1, \dots, x'_n$.  Modify $\gamma$ homotopically as follows:

- At each $x_i$, add a path through $U_i \cap U_{i+1}$ from $x_i$ to $x'_i$ and back.  This is always possible by our restriction on $V_i$.
- The loop obtained this way can be partitioned into paths going from $x'_{i-1}$ to $x'_i$ through $U_i$.  By our assumption on $B$, these paths are each homotopic to the corresponding paths of $\gamma'$.

Hence $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ are homotopic, as required.

Comment: To complete the argument, you would need to do this simultaneously for all $n$, and also choose the component $V_i$.  Therefore you are using the axiom of countable choice.

Comment: @MikhailKatz We only need to show that each loop admits at least one representation, so there is no need to consider more than one loop at a time.  $n$ is fixed by the first decision made, and then we only need to pick finitely many $V_i$.

Comment: How do you choose infinitely many $V_i$ without AC :-)

Comment: @MikhailKatz I don't, but if I needed to, that still wouldn't be a problem because the $V_i$ are chosen from a fixed countable set.

Comment: There are countably many intersections, but from each intersection you need to choose one connected component.  You can't do that without ACC.